# Jquery Draggable and droppable but doesn't accept other droppabe elements

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, droppable

I want the jquery line that make my div draggable but not accept to be droppable

I have elements that is draggable and droppable but I don't want this div to act the same I just want it to be draggable but not droppable with anything

Comment: What do you mean draggable and droppable? Can you give an example, maybe a jsfiddle? I have a feeling you are referring the the jQuery UI `.draggable()` function, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the `.draggable()` and `.droppable()` jQuery UI functions, you can use the `accept` parameter to only accept certain elements to be droppable. This is shown on the jQuery UI reference page for `droppable`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: "#draggable",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                .find("p")
                .html("Dropped!");
        }
    });
});
```

The above code will make `#draggable` and `#draggable-nonvalid` elements draggable, `#droppable` droppable, and will make only `#draggable` be accepted by `#droppable`.

[Link/Source - jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements)